# ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
public Router() // Router is a ContentControl with [ContentProperty(nameof(Routes))]
{
    Routes.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // designer will crash here because NewItems is null...
        if (args.NewItems.Count == 0) return;
        var route = (Route)args.NewItems[0];

        _routesCache[route.Id] = route;
    };
}

public ObservableCollection<Route> Routes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Route>();
```

`CollectionChanged` invokes but `args.NewItems` is `null` and collection is always empty. Is there any way to make it available at design time?

```
<local:Router x:Name="AppRouter">
    <local:Route Id="Home" Type="local:Home" />
    <local:Route Id="Login" Type="local:Login" />
</local:Router>
```

I need to access those two `Route` objects at design time.

Comment: Maybe `CollectionChanged` is invoked multiple times. First for initialization and then when the items are added by the ui. Try omitting your code when it is still null.

Comment: `CollectionChanged` is invoked 2 times. 1 time for Home and 1 time for Login but surprisingly Routes collection is still empty and NewItems is always null. Like designer never really adds it... At run-time, it works perfectly.

Comment: NewItems is only non-null when items are added, moved or replaced. Check the Action property before accessing NewItems.

Comment: @Clemens the action is "Reset" at design-time and "Add" at run-time

Comment: Well, if its Reset, then NewItems is null.

Comment: @Clemens so how can I get new items at design-time then?

Comment: What's in the Routes collection on Reset?

Comment: @Clemens it's always empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by not using `ObservableCollection<T>` as items were always empty at design-time even after `Loaded` event.

I just use `List<T>` now and access the routes in `Loaded` event handler.